# Trying to find a way to get data from another sheet

Tags: excel

I wonder if someone could help me,
I am not a whiz at excel although i know some things, what am after is, I have a worksheets from Monday to Friday, say on a Monday I have time, from, to etc. for car trips, in the 'from' would be the address, I have a list of 1,000 street names on a separate sheet, I want to be able to start typing a street name in the 'from' cell and the street name appear and I can enter it then, is this possible?
I currently have the 1,000 street names above the 'from' column thus it pops up when I start typing, just wanted to know if there was an easier way, as I need to add streets to the list over time, I would be grateful if someone could steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well, you want to implement automatic completion based on data from another worksheet? Google that. Here is what I found :

- http://trumpexcel.com/2013/10/excel-drop-down-list-with-search-suggestions/
- http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=69642&p=362762#post362762 : cf. the June 1st 2007 comment by Dave Hawley